# asp.net mvc forms authentication with no membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a following scenario: user logs in using google account and then I call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name, true);`. In my web.config I have

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms cookieless="UseCookies"  name=".someName" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080"/
</authentication>
```

And that's it, no membership provider, no `dbo.aspnet_*` tables. And that would be fine except sometimes (I don't know why) even when user doesn't close browser and sends requests periodically he becomes non-authenticated again. Can anyone explain why?
And what should I do to make authentication persistent? Would be great if solution wouldn't involve sql server as there isn't any.

Comment: suggestion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx

Comment: i think it's due to timeout, that's mean if user dosn't do any thing for `10080` he will be logout and cookies automaticly removed.

Comment: timeout=”10080″ is meassured in minutes, meaning we got a timeout of 10080 minutes here.  Can you check that cookie is still present in the moment when user is non-auth.

Comment: @Grunf I checked and I saw this in request header: Cookie: __utma=... (that's when user is non-auth already). While when he is auth the header looks like this Cookie: __utma=... .someName=... , which makes me believe he is not sending cookie in the first case. But why?

Comment: It can happen if AppPool is restarted. If you open Machine Key setting in IIS on site level you will see a checkbox "Automatically generaty at runtime" under Decription key section. If the chekcbox set then each AppPool restart will cause key to be changed. It means that forms authentication would not be able to decrytp all existing auth cookies.

Comment: @Vasiliy Shiryaev It seems like this worked! Thank you.